# Big Query - manage user access with views

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, looker-studio

in our project we have tables and views which are build on the tables. The Views have the business logic included and managing the user access:

[image]

So I need a solution for the users able to querying the Views (via BQ or DataStudio) but not having access to the tables...

Comment: Simply grant select on the views?

Comment: Yes, but in Big Query you only have the standard roles for view/read based on the datasets. So my approach would be to have different datasets (Views and Tables) or maybe to create a custom role. I don't know what is the standard way to do so..

Comment: see my answer and consider accepting ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is straight forward:

1. Put your views in a seperate dataset
2. Grant access to that dataset to the your users
3. Give the views access to the tables that they need by sharing the dataset where the tables live and using the `add authorized view` option when sharing it.

This will allow users to access the views, but not the underlying tables.

See [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/share-access-views) more info.

Comment: Does this work for external connections (e.g. Cloud SQL db within the same project)? I can't get it to work, but I can't help thinking I'm missing something